# Python query to Elasticsearch returns 0 hits

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I'm trying to query elastic search for all the logs between two  milliseconds timestamps.

When querying Elasticsearch directly via:

```
curl -XPOST <ElasticSearch> ' -d ' {"query" : { "bool" : { "must" : { "range" : { "received_at" : { "gte" : 1310325395701, "lte" : 1468933745000 } } } } } }'
```

I obtain the desired result. However, the following query from a Python script returns 0 hits:

```
res = es.search(index="syslog-*", body={ "query" : { "bool" : { "must" : { "range" : { "received_at" : { "gte" : 1310325395701, "lte" : 1468933745000 } } } } } }, size=6000)
```

I've also tried this one:

```
res = es.search(index="syslog-*", body= { "query" : { "range" : { "received_at" : { "gte" : 1310325395701, "lte" : 1468933745000 } } } }, size=6000)
```

But exactly the same thing happens. Other kinds of queries from the python script do return hits:

```
res = es.search(index="syslog-*", body={"query": {"match_all": {}}}, size=6000)
```

Where:

```
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection

class MyConnection(RequestsHttpConnection):
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    proxies = kwargs.pop('proxies', {})
    super(MyConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.session.proxies = proxies

es = Elasticsearch([es_url], connection_class=MyConnection, proxies = {'https': 'http://user:pw@proxy.org:port'})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My spontaneous guess is that the index you're using is wrong.  Alternatively, I'd try to eg.get() a document id that you see when curling directly.

Comment: @FrederickNord But the `match_all` query runs fin according to OP, with the same index name.

Comment: @FrederickNord thank you both for your replies. Indeed, the match_all query returns hits. I've tried with different indexes as well but still nothing.

The curl -XPOST query returns logs when querying that index via:

        <subdomain>.amazonaws.com/syslog-*/_search

Comment: @Alex Please post a reproducible snippet, including the declaration of each variable.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I just added the class MyConnection and the declaration of es. Cheers!